# Usage of first() in RxPy

Tags: python, observable, rx-py

How do I recover elements from an `Observable` sequence in RxPy

```
obs = Observable.from_([1,2,3])
print obs.first()
```

should print 1, but it returns another `AnonymousObservable`, instead of the element.

In general, what is the best operator to recover elements from an `Observable` sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
obs = Observable.from_([1,2,3])
first = list(obs.first().to_blocking())[0]
print(first)
```

The `to_blocking` call converts the sequence into an iterator (of type rx.core.blockingobservable.BlockingObservable), and the `list()` 
conversion allows to access the inner values.

Comment: Welcome to answering on SO, it might be helpful to outline _why_ your solution works and the original posters code does not, i.e. why are you calling to_blocking and why are you calling list() etc.